# Google Drive API throws GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Internal Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, internal-server-error

I have the following code to create and update the file in the Google Drive in App Script

```
var resource =
{
  title: 'file name',
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
  parents: [{ id: parentFolderId }]
};

var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(base64String)) //issue occurs due to blob
//if file already exists, we are updating the file.
if (fileExists) {
    Drive.Files.update(resource, fileId, blob);
  }
 else {
    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
  }
```

It started giving Internal error from last few days, it was working fine for so long. I am not able to find the exact reason for the exception because it only returns Internal Error

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Internal Error

**Edit**
I've narrowed down that the blob is causing the issue. I believe there's been a change in Utilities function.

Any suggestion or workaround would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: For sever errors, there's nothing you can do, except  delete this project and recreate the entire project.

Comment: @TheMaster, why to delete the project, there are users using this addon. Is there any other way? What's causing this error?

Comment: @Jayakrishnan Another way is to create a support ticket or a issue in the issuetracker. Other than that, try re-authorizing the project.

Comment: @TheMaster, I've updated the post, can you please check?

Comment: Now, I confirmed your message. From your script, what is the mimeType of the original file of the data of `base64String`?

Comment: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' (MS-Excel)

Comment: @Tanaike, I've sent you exact base64 string in your contact form, please check

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I've sent you exact base64 string in your contact form, please check`, I'm worried that you might have misunderstood my comment. I asked for the mimeType of the original data of `base64String`. I apologize for this.

Comment: By the way, although I'm not sure about the mimeType of the original data of `base64String`, about the original data of `base64String`, when you manually open it by converting it as Google Spreadsheet, if an error occurs, that file cannot be also converted by Drive API. Please be careful about this. In that case, please confirm your original data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251199/discussion-between-jayakrishnan-and-tanaike).